# How did a user with 1 rep comment on an answer?

Tags: support, comment

I was curious to see a [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-intuition-behind-beta-distribution/47782#comment123874_47782) from a [user](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/27997/user27997) who had only 1 reputation on one of my answers (the commenter was *not* the original OP).

The comment was a fine question and I of course had no objection to it, but I was still surprised that it was possible. The [privileges page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) says that the "comment everywhere" privilege is granted only at 50 rep.

Why was this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This user posted his/her comment as an answer (this happens oftentimes, because of reputation issue or a misunderstanding of how the site works), and it was flagged by some vigilant users. A moderator converted it as a proper comment beneath your reply.